# DNS-сервер не резрешает IP-адрес в имя сервера

Tags: ubuntu, dns, active-directory, samba, kerberos

уважаемые! Настраиваю контроллер AD на Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 (это принципиально). Делаю это с помощью samba4 и krb5. В чем собственно проблема. При проверке обнаружилось, что DNS-сервер не может зарезолвить IP-адрес в имя сервера, хотя наоборот - все работает. Уже битый час ковыряюсь, не могу понять в чем дело.

Сеть 192.168.0.1. Адрес сервера 192.168.0.110.

Файл /etc/resolv.conf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл /etc/hosts

[image]

Файл smb.conf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл krb5.conf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В начале настройки отключил systemd-resolved. Вот что выводит nslookup:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарю за ответы, уже намучался с этим...

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: что у вас там в качестве nameserver-а работает?

Comment: Обратная зона, при развертывании AD samba4, не создается автоматический. Ее можно создать вручную https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/DNS_Administration#To_create_a_.2F24_reverse_zone

Comment: Касаемо текста - делаю все на виртуалке, буффер не настраивал, прошу прощения за неудобства)
Обратную зону создал - ситуацию не исправило, теперь ругается, server can't find ... : NXDOMAIN
А про nameserver не понял вопроса, я, честно говоря дилетант в таких вещах, так что не серчайте сильно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, большое спасибо! Как указанно в комментариях, обратная зона не создается автоматически, необходимо это делать вручную. Мне помогло:

```
samba-tool dns zonecreate godfather 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa
samba-tool dns add godfather.cartel.cartel 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa 110 PTR godfather.cartel.cartel
```

Правда теперь все еще не отображается сервер в сетевом окружении на терминалах, но это уже проблема будущего меня)